# when i use vuetify, i can't show images

Tags: vue.js, icons, vuetify.js

i added some icons on navigation-drawer, but it don't show me any icon.

```
<v-list-item-icon>
     <v-icon left small>email</v-icon>
</v-list-item-icon>
```

i used email icon of the vuetify serves, as you can see.

and i also registered a image inside a v-card, but vuetify just gave me an error.(no image i wanted)

here is my v-card-media.

```
<v-card-media src="./assets/teras.jpg">
</v-card-media>
```

below is error message.

webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:620 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly?

how can i solve this problem?? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkgC5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to your icon problem you should put the proper name of the icon. Please refer here https://materialdesignicons.com/cdn/2.0.46/

```
<v-icon left small>mdi-email-outline</v-icon>
```

That is the proper way of adding icon.

v-card-media is already deprecated.

Try v-img instead.